# jquery counter does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, counter

I have 2 counters on my site that count up when I load my page. but when my screen comes under 800px width. They do not automatically start when I load the page.

However, If I scroll really quick to the spot they are located on the site. They DO start. And fullscreen they also work fine. And on mobile they also work.

Here is the jquery code:

```
if (jQuery('.shortcode_counter').size() > 0) {
    if (jQuery(window).width() > 760) {
        jQuery('.shortcode_counter').each(function(){
            if (jQuery(this).offset().top < jQuery(window).height()) {
                if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('done')) {
                    var set_count = jQuery(this).find('.stat_count').attr('data-count');
                    jQuery(this).find('.stat_temp').stop().animate({width: set_count}, {duration: 3000, step: function(now) {
                            var data = Math.floor(now);
                            jQuery(this).parents('.counter_wrapper').find('.stat_count').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                    jQuery(this).addClass('done');
                    jQuery(this).find('.stat_count');
                }
            } else {
                jQuery(this).waypoint(function(){
                    if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('done')) {
                        var set_count = jQuery(this).find('.stat_count').attr('data-count');
                        jQuery(this).find('.stat_temp').stop().animate({width: set_count}, {duration: 3000, step: function(now) {
                                var data = Math.floor(now);
                                jQuery(this).parents('.counter_wrapper').find('.stat_count').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery(this).addClass('done');
                        jQuery(this).find('.stat_count');
                    }
                },{offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not great with jquery. This is the jquery code that I have tried:

- `if (jQuery(window).width() > 760) {` to `if (jQuery(window).width() > 0) {`
  Becouse min screenwidht might be it?
- `if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('done')) {` Just completely removed this if statement. Becouse I thought it did apply the class or something.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 module_number_5 module_cont pb50 module_counter">
        <div class="module_content shortcode_counter breedte-100">
            <div class="counter_wrapper">
                 <div class="counter_content">
                     <div class="stat_count_wrapper">
                         <h1 class="stat_count speciale-grote-counter" data-count="{{ records[1].number }}">0</h1>
                     </div>
                     <div class="counter_body">
                         <h5 class="counter_title speciale-grote-counter-text">{{ records[1].year }}</h5>
                     <div class="stat_temp"></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I have no clue on this one. So I thought to post it here. In the meantime I am trying to work this out.

So if anyone knows the solution to this. Please.

Thanks in advance! Happy coding.

ADITION:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9q0eLvs1/) Added working jsfiddle. problem is. My error only occurs when the counter is not in the screen initially. and under 800px width. And in JSFIDDLE it always is in the screen right?

ADITION 2:

Ive found out its this exact row. :

```
jQuery(this).waypoint(function(){

},{offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
```

ADITION 3:

Apparantly some other row I found were the problem. I have put it in an answer beneath but ill also include it here:

Deleted :

```
jQuery(this).waypoint(function(){

},{offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
```

Now works perfectly fine.

Comment: can you provide a working FIDDLE?

Comment: ill try. give me a sec. @DavidHope

Comment: @DavidHope Added jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "My error only occurs when the counter is not in the screen initially."

But is this what you were looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/9q0eLvs1/3/

The only thing that i changed was this line:

```
if (jQuery(window).width() > 260) {
```

Further more, if you don't require the `width()` then you can simply remove it and your code should look like this:

```
if (jQuery('.shortcode_counter').size() > 0) {

            jQuery('.shortcode_counter').each(function(){
                if (jQuery(this).offset().top < jQuery(window).height()) {
                    if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('done')) {
                        var set_count = jQuery(this).find('.stat_count').attr('data-count');
                        jQuery(this).find('.stat_temp').stop().animate({width: set_count}, {duration: 3000, step: function(now) {
                                var data = Math.floor(now);
                                jQuery(this).parents('.counter_wrapper').find('.stat_count').html(data);
                            }
                        });
                        jQuery(this).addClass('done');
                        jQuery(this).find('.stat_count');
                    }
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).waypoint(function(){
                        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('done')) {
                            var set_count = jQuery(this).find('.stat_count').attr('data-count');
                            jQuery(this).find('.stat_temp').stop().animate({width: set_count}, {duration: 3000, step: function(now) {
                                    var data = Math.floor(now);
                                    jQuery(this).parents('.counter_wrapper').find('.stat_count').html(data);
                                }
                            });
                            jQuery(this).addClass('done');
                            jQuery(this).find('.stat_count');
                        }
                    },{offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
                }
            });

    }
```

Here is a FIDDLE without the width() scenario:

https://jsfiddle.net/9q0eLvs1/4/

Comment: Ive found out its the `if (jQuery(this).offset().top < jQuery(window).height())` if else statement. however it goes into the else linked to ^ that if statement. and there something goes wrong

Comment: Now even more accurate. its this sentence: 
`jQuery(this).waypoint(function(){` and `},{offset: 'bottom-in-view'});`

Comment: Ive found the problem @David Hope. Still ill accept your answer becouse u got me in the right direction. so Upvote and Hook for u :D

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly It was this function:

```
jQuery(this).waypoint(function(){

},{offset: 'bottom-in-view'});
```

Ive deleted the rows and it works perfectly fine again.